# Using NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription to request user disable ITP for WKWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, application-settings

The iOS 14 release is catching third-party auth/device cookies and it appears we need to disable Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP). The documentation available (planet.webkit.org) suggests we would set a specific setting key and "Purpose String" in the project's Info.plist:

> **Intelligent Tracking Prevention in WKWebView**
>
> Additionally in iOS 14.0 and macOS Big Sur, Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP), is enabled
> by default in all WKWebView applications. [...]
>
> In some extreme cases, users might need to disable ITP protections,
> for example when relying on web content outside of the app developer’s
> control. **Applications can signal the need to allow users to disable
> ITP by adding a Purpose String for the key
> `NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription` to the app’s Info.plist.** When
> present, this key causes the application’s Settings screen to display
> a user control to disable ITP. The setting cannot be read or changed
> through API calls.

https://planet.webkit.org/

I believe I have done this:

```
<!-- Info.plist -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow authentication and device trackers.</string>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

I would expect a modal iOS dialog to display asking for the permission using that text to explain the permission request. However, I never receive any dialog or request and ITP is still interfering in the auth/device recognition process.

It might hinge on what the following means in practice.

> this key causes the application’s Settings screen to display a user control to disable ITP.

How do I get this process to work and allow for disabling ITP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to add a Settings bundle (or similar) that allows the iOS device to present a settings page from the device's Settings app. Essentially, follow the [`Settings.bundle` tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) and the `Info.plist` setting for `NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription` will trigger the setting toggle in the screenshot below.

Not sure why it doesn't use the "Purpose String" value, however.

[image: Settings for app]

Comment: Does it work? see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886177/wkwebview-allow-cross-website-tracking-setting-not-working

Comment: Adding the Settings bundle is what makes it work.

Comment: do we have to do anything in settings bundle ?  as same thing we can achieve same thing by just adding NSCrossWebsiteTrackingUsageDescription into plist file ..  the problem which I'm facing is that switch is not working properly , it get refreshed when you come back on setting screen.

Comment: @NamanVaishnav I imported the bundle and had the setting in the project's `Info.plist`. That was it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. In my situation we are loading an embedded tableau view (in an iframe)